Positioning of figures are automatically changed
Why position of figures are automatically changed and figures moved on to last page

The short version is that if you don't give the [p] option but the figure is too big, then it gets delayed until you have a \clearpage or the end of the document.  If you don't want the figure to automatically change to what LaTeX thinks is best, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8625/107497.

The only reason to use figure is to allow the content to "float" ie have its position changed. If it floats to the end it presumbaly means that your figure had no valid place to be inserted, but as you have shown no example we can not say why that is the case here. But for exanple if you use [t] on a figure that is more than 70% of the page height it will go to the end as it is not allowed at the top of a text page and the option removes p so it is not allowed to go on a page on is own.
